# Ag-grid conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Is it possible using the framework ag-grid in JS to apply a conditional background color formatting of a cell based on its value such as Excel conditional formatting (eg the second table formatting in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/highlight-patterns-and-trends-with-conditional-formatting-eea152f5-2a7d-4c1a-a2da-c5f893adb621) is a great example of what I am trying to achieve).

Basically, cells containing the highest values are green and tend to be red as they lower, being yellow when they reach the median (the inverse is applied in above link)

As you see, it is not a simple CellClassRules as the cell color depends cell values across the table and not only a specific row or column.

I didn’t find such option on ag-grid documentation.

Comment: write a function which looks at values for the row, works out which colour each cell should be based on value, and apply a background color, [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pKNYp3ZtpATTYuXv).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On your example, the formatting is per row. If you check this https://plnkr.co/edit/kFh0Bir6ul8J3yDx , you can see that in the first row 9 is green, and second row 3 is green. What I need is to have the formatting as if all the number where contained in a unique row, so that low number across the table are red and higher numbers green.

Comment: looks correct to me, the highest value PER ROW will be green, but I'm guessing you want the gradient across the table? You'll just need to tweak the logic to take other rows into account, should be fairly easy.

Comment: Yes I would like the gradient across the row and don’t quite know how to tweak the function to get it.

Comment: it does work across the row, the highest value per row is green, the lowest being red. what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, across the table*

Comment: something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/6tPuPPrXNOExgWBb). let me know if it works.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much. Will need to tweak it to change the brown color into yellow. And exclude the first column as it will be a text column. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function for the `cellStyle` and have this function look at each and every value in the table, determine it's ranking, then have it return the relevant colour for the cell, i.e. the lower it is, return a more "reddish" colour, the higher it is, return a "greener" colour. Something like this:

```
function myCellStyleFunction(params) {
  const totalCellCount = params.api.getDisplayedRowCount() * columnsCount;
  let allValuesInTable = [];

  rowData.forEach((x) => {  
    const valuesForRow = Object.keys(x).map(function (k) {
      return x[k];
    });
    allValuesInTable = allValuesInTable.concat(valuesForRow);
  });
  
  const valuesForTableOrdered = allValuesInTable.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  
  const valueIndex = valuesForTableOrdered.indexOf(params.value);
  console.log(valueIndex)
  debugger;
  const bgColour = generateColor('#FF0000','#00FF00',totalCellCount,valueIndex)

  return { backgroundColor: '#' + bgColour };
}
```

And apply this `cellStyle` in `defaultColDef` so it is applied to every cell.

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6tPuPPrXNOExgWBb?preview).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the Gradient Column feature and it will do it all for you with a couple of clicks?
https://demo.adaptabletools.com/style/aggridgradientcolumndemo

Comment: Because I want the gradient to be applied based on all cell values across every columns/rows

Comment: This won't help the OP as that formats the style based just on that column only and not the whole row.  Plus its an AdapTable function and not a native ag-Grid one.  It CAN be done very easily in AdapTable but through using Conditional Styles as they can look at the whole row in the style expression.  However there is no indication that the OP is using AdapTable that I can see.